# System settings are not being saved

Tags: 16.04, system-settings

I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I make changes to the systems settings, they are not saved. When I go back to the particular settings they show selection from before making a change. Making a change and restarting the system does not help, either. I've tried various settings like Power, Appearance, Brightness & Lock, Time & Date, experiencing the same result.

Has anyone experienced similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, what are you using to change the system settings? You can try dconf-editor or Ubuntu Tweaks which may help you keep things persistent. I have used both with success over the past few years.

Comment: I use GUI interface to the system settings. I access it from the upper right corner menu (I assume all Ubuntu installations have it there), where there is the selection of user accounts, system shutdown, about, etc.

Comment: You might consider using Ubuntu Tweaks or dconf-editor to make the changes persistent.

Comment: I considered Ubuntu Tweaks but it doesn't help. When I change Power setting from "suspend" to "nothing" it still reverts it to "suspend" after the next entry to Power. Also dconf-editor does't help.